# Discord GitHub Webhook add role ping

Tags: discord, webhooks, git-webhooks

I am using a Webhook to integrate Discord with GitHub for sending messages when a repository has been pushed to. However, I want the webhook to automatically ping a certain role (I have an @Updates role in the server) whenever this happens.

Is there are way to ping a role or even add text to a Discord GitHub Webhook? If not, is there a bot or other service that pings a certain role whenever a message is sent in a certain channel?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this outlines how to do it with webhooks: https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/other/discord_markdown.html

Comment: But how do you change the value of `content` when using GitHub? Is there any way to do that @effprime?